# How can I Trace Route using TIdTraceRoute from Indy?

Tags: exception, delphi, indy, delphi-11-alexandria, traceroute

Whenever I try to Trace the route of a Host, then I get the following error:

> raised exception class EIdSocketError with message 'Socket Error # 10040 Message too long.'

These are my component design-time properties:

```
  object IdTraceRoute: TIdTraceRoute
    ReceiveTimeout = 5000
    Protocol = 1
    ProtocolIPv6 = 58
    ResolveHostNames = True
    OnReply = IdTraceRouteReply
    Left = 640
    Top = 472
  end
```

This is my code:

```
procedure TFrame_TraceRoute.TraceRoute;
begin
  memOutput.Lines.Clear;

  IdTraceRoute.ReceiveTimeout := Round(sbTimeout.Value);
  IdTraceRoute.PacketSize := Round(sbPacketSize.Value);
  IdTraceRoute.Host := edtIPDomain.Text;

  memOutput.Lines.Add('Pings:');
  memOutput.Lines.Add('======================================');

  IdTraceRoute.Trace();
end;

procedure TFrame_TraceRoute.IdTraceRouteReply(ASender: TComponent; const AReplyStatus: TReplyStatus);
begin
  if AReplyStatus.ReplyStatusType = rsEcho then
  begin
    var RoundTripTime := AReplyStatus.MsRoundTripTime;
    memOutput.Lines.Add('Reply from ' + AReplyStatus.FromIpAddress + ': time=' + RoundTripTime.ToString + 'ms');
  end
  else if AReplyStatus.ReplyStatusType = rsTimeout then
    memOutput.Lines.Add('Ping request timed out')
  else
    memOutput.Lines.Add('Ping request failed');
end;
```

My code is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/shaunroselt/Roselt-Developer-Tools/blob/master/Tools/App/uFrame_TraceRoute.pas) if you want to see the full unit.

The error happens as soon as `IdTraceRoute.Trace()` is called.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12723081/2908017) where the error is the same when doing a ping via `TIdIcmpClient` and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723820/2908017) suggests setting the `PacketSize` to 24. This doesn't fix my issue though. I've set the `PacketSize` to 24 and even lower, but I still get the same error.

When I do a ping with [`TIdIcmpClient`](https://github.com/shaunroselt/Roselt-Developer-Tools/blob/master/Tools/App/uFrame_PingIPDomain.pas) and the same properties (ReceiveTimeout, PacketSize, Host, etc), then it works. Although once I switch to doing Trace Route using `TIdTraceRoute`, then it doesn't work.

---

What am I doing wrong? What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: @KenWhite I've replaced the images with error text and an extract from the `.fmx` file for the properties, but I don't agree with not sending a screenshot of the properties, because not all properties are showing in the `.fmx` file due to them being on default. So a screenshot works much better, but in any case, I've removed the screenshot and replaced it.

Comment: "*I don't agree with not sending a screenshot of the properties, because not all properties are showing in the .fmx file due to them being on default*" - which means anyone trying to reproduce the issue will have the same defaults, and so only need the non-default values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay. Makes sense 

Comment: Error 10040 is `WSAEMSGSIZE`, which means the client tried to receive a datagram that is larger than can fit in its receive buffer. The problem is not with the `PacketSize` property, that merely limits the max size that user-defined data can be.  Why the receive buffer is too small, I do not know, as `TIdIcmpClient` (which `TIdTraceRoute` derives from) calculates the receive buffer size based on how much data it is sending out and expects to echo back. Something in the trace is likely echoing back larger datagrams than expected.

Comment: @RemyLebeau When I do a ping with TIdIcmpClient, then that works perfectly fine without any issues. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: TraceRoute is just a series of Pings, the size of the data packets shouldn't change between each step. You'll have to debug the network traffic to see what is really going on. Is there a particular packet that is causing the error at a particular step?